# Does central limit theorem (CLT) hold for non-integer values of $n$?

Tags: self-study, central-limit-theorem

[image]
[image]
Why I think it might be correct:

Search “not an integer” in http://www.randomservices.org/random/sample/CLT.html and you would find 2 occurrences of the author stating that CLT is valid even if $n$ is not an integer.

Why I think it might be wrong:

If $X$ is assumed to be Poisson, then I can see why CLT still holds for non-integer values of $n$. But I don’t see why CLT should hold for all possible distributions for $X$. The 2 proofs for CLT at http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~yuvalf/CLT.pdf don’t make sense to me for non-integer values of $n$.

Comment: Can you explain for us how $n$, the number of observations, could not be an integer?

Comment: The Central Limit Theorem does not say anything at all about integers.  What, then, do you mean when you ask "if [the] CLT does indeed hold for non-integer values"?

Comment: Sorry, everyone, for not being clear. I've made changes which are highlighted in yellow. @kjetil

Comment: Hi, @gung. Could you help me remove the "on hold" status? I hope my rephrased question is clear now.